# View has child view

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy

*
Iam setting views in scrollable view in winodw i get view by using Alloy.createController(.js).getView.open();. But that view is not showing in scrollable view.

Error:
TiViewProxy: (KrollRuntimeThread) [18207,310579] Add called with a null child*

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this documentation for more info: 
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Controllers

You should have a viewToAddName.js inside app > controllers - for proper alloy code you should also have a viewToAddName.xml in app > views and a viewToAddName.tss in app > styles

You should call the create view and then add that view to the scrollable view as below

```
var viewToAdd = Alloy.createController('viewToAddName').getView();      

// $.scrollableView should be the ID/Name of you scrollable View
$.scrollableView.add(viewToAdd);
```